# Update schema changes using Microsoft sync framework 2.1

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

Is this possible to update the server side and Ce(local) Schema using sync framework 2.1.

1) Currently Sync is working fine. If i update server schema(adding an extra column to table).
   How to reflect this in SqlCe(Local)?

2) Is this kind of scenario Supported in MSF 4.0?

Answer (score 3):

there is nothing in Sync Fx 4.0 around updating scope configuration to reflect schema changes. (there is now Sync Fx 4 either. What used to be known as Sync Fx CTP 4 was released as Sync Framework Toolkit)

if you're up to it, you can hack the scope_config to alter the scope configuration, see:

[Modifying Sync Framework Scope Definition – Part 1 – Introduction](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/modifying-sync-framework-scope-definition-part-1-introduction/)

[Modifying Sync Framework Scope Definition – Part 2 – Workarounds](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/modifying-sync-framework-scope-definition-part-2-workarounds/)

[Modifying Sync Framework Scope Definition – Part 3 – Workarounds – Adding/Removing Columns](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/modifying-sync-framework-scope-definition-part-3-workarounds-addingremoving-columns/)

[Modifying Sync Framework Scope Definition – Part 4 – Workarounds – Adding a Table to an existing scope](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/modifying-sync-framework-scope-definition-part-4-workarounds-adding-a-table-to-an-existing-scope/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. You just need to drop the scope, recreate it and perform the sync again. I am not sure if this is available in MSF 4.0

Comment: if you just drop the scope and recreate it and both databases contain data already, you will run into conflicts because dropping the scope effectively wipes out the sync knowledge of what was synched. both replica will be sending updates to each other that already exists...